# running batch file with perl scripts in it on entire folder

Tags: perl, batch-file, cmd

I have 3 Perl scripts and i run them through batch file

Script.bat

```
perl script1.pl %1
perl script2.pl %1
perl script3.pl %1
```

I run it from cmd, by just running the script.bat and file name(.C files)

```
script.bat <file_name>
```

How do i make it run for all the files in a specific folder

for example

FOLDER ABCD has files a.c, b.c and d.c

then after typing the command

```
script.bat ABCD
```

all the three files i.e a.c, b.c and d.c should get executed

Comment: The proper way would be to alter your script to accept a list of files instead of just one file. E.g. put a loop around it such as `for my $file (@ARGV)` and then call it with `perl script.pl ABCD/*`. Although if you are in Windows, the shell will not glob for you, so you need to do that yourself with `@ARGV = map glob, @ARGV`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -le "-f and print and `script.bat $_` for map <$_/*>, pop||'.'" ABCD
```

it defaults to current dir when no folder name given.

Comment: ok.. but this command has to be run through command line.but i need a perl script so that anyone else(who doesn't even know perl) can run it

Comment: @Ad-vic you can put it in another `.bat` file? :)

Comment: excuting the batch file containing the above code just prints it, doesn't execute

Comment: @Ad-vic I've added output for files which are passed to script.bat so it can be easier to debug.